# Divide by a number which is not power of 2 in Verilog RTL coding

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level

For multiplication and division, we can use the left and right shifts.

```
x>>2  // it will right shift by 2. ---> 2^2=4. (Multiply by 4 or divide by 4, depends on MSB/LSB)
```

However, if we want to divide by a number that isn't the power of 2, how can we achieve the required purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booth's algorithm is an additive one and can take a comparatively longer time than the multiplicative algorithms, like the Newton-Raphson algorithms found [in this educational PDF.](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee486/doc/chap5.pdf)

Each next approximation is calculated using the previous approximation.

**X**(N+1) = **X**(N)(2 - b * **X**(N)), where x(0)=1

So, to find the inverse of b, i.e. 1/b, where b=0.6 (error=e(x)), it takes about 5 iterations.

1. **X**(000) = **1.000**
2. **X**(001) = **1.000** * (2 - (**1.000** * 0.6)) = **1.400**
3. **X**(002) = **1.400** * (2 - (**1.400** * 0.6)) = **1.624**
4. **X**(003) = **1.624** * (2 - (**1.624** * 0.6)) = **1.6655744**
5. **X**(004) = **X**(003) * (2 - (**X**(003) * 0.6)) = **1.666665951**
6. **X**(005) = **X**(004) * (2 - (**X**(004) * 0.6)) = **1.666666668**

which approximates the answer, which is 1.6666666667.

I included this example in case the referenced PDF disappears. See the referenced PDF or look up the Newton-Raphson algorithm for more information.

Answer (score 0):

By using Booth's restoring division algorithm